# Webbrowser control throws exception when Form windowstate is minimized

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am using WebBrowser control on a WinForm. When my form is minimized the control throws an exception,

> An outgoing call cannot be made since the application is dispatching
>   an input-synchronous call. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010D
>   (RPC_E_CANTCALLOUT_ININPUTSYNCCALL))

I have stated windowstate as,

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

Does anyone aware of this issue ?

Thanks in advance,
Vijay

Comment: I have run an application with webbrowser control with this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
 No problem occurred. I think your problem is in other code.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to modify the UI elements on the other thread.

Comment: If I am correct to select your problem then the solution will be invoke method. Solution is given in answer. If problem is not solved then comment please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you want to modify UI from other thread use invoke method

```
        if (control.InvokeRequired)
        { 
            control.Invoke( (MethodInvoker)( ()=> control.updatingfunction() ) ;

        }
        else
        {
            control.updatingfunction();
        }
```

suppose you want to hide a panel (named panel1) from other thread. Then your code will be

```
       if (panel1.InvokeRequired)
        { 
            panel1.Invoke( (MethodInvoker)( ()=> panel1.Hide() )) ;

        }
        else
        {
            panel1.Hide();
        }
```